# Input pipeline using TensorFlow Dataset API and Pandas?

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to create a TensorFlow Dataset that takes in a list of path names for CSV files and create batches of training data. First I create a parse function which uses Pandas to read the first n rows. I give this function as argument for the 'map' method in Dataset

```
def _get_data_for_dataset(file_name,rows=100):
  print(file_name.decode())

  df_input=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_name, file_name.decode()),
                     usecols =['Wind_MWh','Actual_Load_MWh'],nrows = rows)

  X_data = df_input.as_matrix()
  X_data.astype('float32', copy=False)

  return X_data

 dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(file_names)
 dataset = dataset2.map(lambda file_name: tf.py_func(_get_data_for_dataset,[file_name,100], tf.float64))
 dataset= dataset.batch(2) #Create batches
 iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
 get_batch = iter.get_next()

with tf.Session() as sess:
  print(sess.run(get_batch).shape)
```

The above code works but instead of producing a dataset with shape (200,2) it produces a dataset with shape (2, 100, 2). Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got the answer from [Dataset API 'flat_map' method producing error for same code which works with 'map' method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116343/dataset-api-flat-map-method-producing-error-for-same-code-which-works-with-ma/49140725#49140725)
I am posting the full code in case it may help others who want to use Pandas and Dataset API together.

```
folder_name = './data/power_data/'
file_names = os.listdir(folder_name)

def _get_data_for_dataset(file_name):
    df_input=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_name, file_name.decode()),
                         usecols=['Wind_MWh', 'Actual_Load_MWh'])
    X_data = df_input.as_matrix()
    return X_data.astype('float32', copy=False)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(file_names)

# Use `Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` to make a `Dataset` from the output of 
# the `tf.py_func()` op.
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda file_name: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    tf.py_func(_get_data_for_dataset, [file_name], tf.float32)))

dataset = dataset.batch(100)

iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
get_batch = iter.get_next()

  with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(get_batch))
```