# Dataset API 'flat_map' method producing error for same code which works with 'map' method

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to create a create a pipeline to read multiple CSV files using TensorFlow Dataset API and Pandas. However, using the `flat_map` method is producing errors. However, if I am using `map` method I am able to build the code and run it in session. This is the code I am using. I already opened [#17415](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17415) issue in TensorFlow Github repository. But apparently, it is not an error and they asked me to post here.

```
folder_name = './data/power_data/'
file_names = os.listdir(folder_name)
def _get_data_for_dataset(file_name,rows=100):#
    print(file_name.decode())

    df_input=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_name, file_name.decode()),
                         usecols =['Wind_MWh','Actual_Load_MWh'],nrows = rows)
    X_data = df_input.as_matrix()
    X_data.astype('float32', copy=False)

    return X_data
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(file_names)
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda file_name: tf.py_func(_get_data_for_dataset, 
[file_name], tf.float64))
dataset= dataset.batch(2)
fiter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
get_batch = iter.get_next()
```

I get the following error: `map_func must return a Dataset object`. The pipeline works without error when I use `map` but it doesn't give the output I want. For example, if Pandas is reading N rows from each of my CSV files I want the pipeline to concatenate data from B files and give me an array with shape (N*B, 2). Instead, it is giving me (B, N,2) where B is the Batch size. `map` is adding another axis instead of concatenating on the existing axis. From what I understood in the documentation `flat_map` is supposed to give a flatted output. In the documentation, both `map` and `flat_map` returns type Dataset. So how is my code working with map and not with flat_map?

It would also great if you could point me towards code where Dataset API has been used with Pandas module.

Comment: We don't have access to your data. Can you create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example to reproduce this problem?

Comment: The data consists of CSV files with two feature columns namely 'Wind_MWh' and 'Actual_Load_MWh'.

Comment: I see what the problem is now. Indeed, both `map` and `flat_map` return a `Dataset`. But, the mapped functions have different requirements: for `map`, the `lambda` must return a tensor, for `flat_map`, it must return a `Dataset`. See the examples e.g. [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#consuming_text_data)

Comment: The examples are very different from what I want to do. It is using tf.data.TextLineDataset(filename) in the lambda function instead of tf.py_func. Can you tell me how I can make the py_func return data set?

Comment: Yes, you can do that the same way you could construct a dataset in any other case. For example`d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(x)` and then just `return d`.

Comment: I added `d = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors(X_data)` to the py_function and returned d. However I am still getting the same error `map_func must return a Dataset object`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As [mikkola points out in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116343/dataset-api-flat-map-method-producing-error-for-same-code-which-works-with-ma#comment85240575_49116343), the [`Dataset.map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#map) and [`Dataset.flat_map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map) expect functions with different signatures: `Dataset.map()` takes a function that maps a single element of the input dataset to a single new element, whereas `Dataset.flat_map()` takes a function that maps a single element of the input dataset to a `Dataset` of elements.

If you want each row of the array returned by `_get_data_for_dataset()` to 
become a separate element, you should use `Dataset.flat_map()` and convert the output of `tf.py_func()` to a `Dataset`, using [`Dataset.from_tensor_slices()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#from_tensor_slices):

```
folder_name = './data/power_data/'
file_names = os.listdir(folder_name)

def _get_data_for_dataset(file_name, rows=100):
    df_input=pd.read_csv(os.path.join(folder_name, file_name.decode()),
                         usecols=['Wind_MWh', 'Actual_Load_MWh'], nrows=rows)
    X_data = df_input.as_matrix()
    return X_data.astype('float32', copy=False)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(file_names)

# Use `Dataset.from_tensor_slices()` to make a `Dataset` from the output of 
# the `tf.py_func()` op.
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda file_name: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
    tf.py_func(_get_data_for_dataset, [file_name], tf.float32)))

dataset = dataset.batch(2)

iter = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
get_batch = iter.get_next()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the above code worked and did not throw any error. I had been trying to solve this for the better part of a week and had almost given up. The Dataset  produced by the pipeline is exactly want. I am able to read from multiple CSV files depending on the size of the batch I want.

Comment: @ mikkola Please (if you can) give me a suggestion to tackle a similar problem:  access a data-set composed of compressed pandas matrices, each in a separate directory. I don't know how to use the mapping function so that it access each matrix separately. In running a variation of this code, it allows me to access each row iteratively, but I want to access the entire matrix  (see my post here). [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51623671/tensorflow-pipeline-for-pickled-pandas-data-input]