# TensorFlow Dataset.flat_map() leads to uneven batches

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

Loading my inputs from files containing 10 samples each, and batching them with 4 samples per batch, I get batches of uneven sizes 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 2, etc., instead of batches combining samples from consecutive files as I expect after flattening the dataset.

I am using TensorFlow 1.8.0. To get data from files into my Dataset object I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116343/dataset-api-flat-map-method-producing-error-for-same-code-which-works-with-ma). My input pipeline looks like this:

```
# Initialize dataset on files
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(input_files_list)

# Pre-process data in parallel
def preprocess_fn(input_file):
    # lots of logic here...
    return input1, input2, input3

map_fn = lambda input_file: tf.py_func(
    preprocess_fn, [input_file], [tf.float32, tf.float32, tf.float32])
dataset = dataset.map(map_func=map_fn, num_parallel_calls=4)

# Flatten from files to samples
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda *x: tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(x))

dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=4)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=8)
```

But what I see is that samples are not actually concatenated between the input files, so that the batch sizes are uneven. I think this is because [`flat_map()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#flat_map) maps each element (all input samples from a file) to a dataset - so after the `flat_map()` my dataset is actually a dataset of datasets, and each nested dataset is batched separately.

But this is not what I intended. How do I concatenate the nested datasets, or otherwise flatten the dataset so that samples from different files can be batched together?

Comment: I had a similar issue, I used `tf.stack` after preprocessing my data. If this doesn't help you, I can post a code snippet showing my full input pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the similar problem with TF 2.0 and I've used `unbatch` function, like so:

```
dataset = dataset.flat_map(lambda f: parse_function(f)).apply(tf.data.experimental.unbatch())
```

I believe in TF 1.8 [tf.contrib.data.unbatch](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.8/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/unbatch) could be used.